# Error while generating a signed APK with Quickblox

Tags: java, android, android-studio, quickblox-android

I am building a chat application using Quickblox and I am getting this error while generating signed APK:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':main:transformJackWithJackForProdRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.jack.Main with arguments {-D jack.dex.optimize=true -D jack.reporter=sdk -D jack.dex.debug.vars=false --classpath /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/preJackRuntimeLibraries/prod/release/jars/8000/40/org.apache.http.legacy-129539f0b824603b057ffaec25d1012211251c2e.jar:/home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/preJackRuntimeLibraries/prod/release/jars/8000/40/android-60050717b8d86015e36ada0f66239378069c5ff5.jar --import /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/preJackPackagedLibraries/prod/release/jars/8000/1f/classes-4fc1a758d450db1c1263a0cb74a71b13317b6815.jar --import /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/preJackPackagedLibraries/prod/release/jars/8000/1f/support-annotations-23.1.1-7c12888f114607254fca82898d5f7b836a860f27.jar --import /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/preJackPackagedLibraries/prod/release/jars/8000/1f/quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc-2.4-31af792cfa1e276d707cb7f9eca755c85d40572b.jar --import /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/preJackPackagedLibraries/prod/release/jars/8000/1f/classes-b579c9ae568209b259d7073a08fa0cbf45ec50b2.jar --import /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/preJackPackagedLibraries/prod/release/jars/8000/1f/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11-b4a8ffc217969591af5d53961f1d25c4620fce4d.jar --import /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/preJackPackagedLibraries/prod/release/jars/8000/1f/classes-b49274b7b0791a281ad07b1165aada160256d567.jar --import /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/preJackPackagedLibraries/prod/release/jars/8000/1f/classes-45ec7a122d7029caba3dd1e5edd222b8200d4a4b.jar --output-dex /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/transforms/jack/prod/release/folders/1000/1f/main --output-jack /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/packaged/prod/release/classes.zip -D jack.import.type.policy=keep-first -D jack.import.resource.policy=keep-first --config-proguard /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/build/intermediates/proguard-files/proguard-android.txt-2.3.1 --config-proguard /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/proguard-project.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/27f3a0250f2b9ccbc3428da3b248c6ab80f404be/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/a51d27e055458d425fc03ebd4a69e3857e26f404/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/05c2a06622ff133df33e6f322189634ea566391f/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/7076a1c700b413036104d3151fcbdf2d5046d066/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/0205a85888d45f0a18803ca588f092d7219e1939/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/c389707f682ca46941376b998e35c619c0018170/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/947942e55d2bdf5170711daac8d4fd08c0ae86c6/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/e4451e6461fdbc20f495936501954ad7390a2323/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/2f91a4089a86443b51bef628825c836c1070b811/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/5660953e3b8026a354bf4bb8e9b90d50e7b19255/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/ea215db295d3f49ad83eb3567e1992c7ce1f10d9/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/.android/build-cache/163b9d1509bf34704c5cd7e2442052cab4b8ef5b/output/proguard.txt --config-proguard /home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/proguard-rules/prod/release/aapt_rules.txt -D jack.obfuscation.mapping.dump=true -D jack.obfuscation.mapping.dump.file=/home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/outputs/mapping/prod/release/mapping.txt --multi-dex legacy -D jack.java.source.version=1.7 -D jack.android.min-api-level=11 -D jack.annotation-processor.source.output=/home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/generated/source/apt/prod/release @/home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/build/intermediates/jack/prod/release/ecj-options.txt}
```

Could someone tell me how to deal with this?

Comment: Few things that i would like to know first....Have you modified proguard??
other thing is, this is just a shot you can try..go to `/home/aaditya/Android_Projects/Tudime/tudime/ciaoim/main/` and delete `build` folder. Clean and then rebuild application.

Comment: No i have not modified proguard. I have just removed few libraries from jnilibs folder. When i rebuild application after deleting the build folder then same error comes. Its generating few jar files in preJackPackagedLibraries folder of transform folder in intermediates in build folder. These jar files are giving problem as you can see above error

Comment: Jack is basically a compiler which links all the required libraries, this is an inbuilt process which every app follows. there will be some issue with your libraries. Lemme implement a sample tonite using this lib. and i will try to regenerate this issue, will keep you posted